# ADD multiple Files to a docker but just RUN one of them

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, docker-container

It's just a theoretical question. Is there a way to run the docker but only run one specific script without changing the Dockerfile? Maybe with the `docker run [container]` command?

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM python:3.8

ADD main1.py
ADD main2.py
ADD main3.py
ADD main4.py
ADD main5.py
```

**Theoretical Command:**

`docker run docker-test main2.py`

Comment: That should work pretty much exactly as you described.  I'd still set some default `CMD` in the image (and generally prefer `COPY` to `ADD`, unless you want to download a URL or unpack an archive file). Does it work if you try it?

Comment: @DavidMaze I tried it now like this:

**Dockerfile**

`FROM python:3.8`

`ADD main.py .`
`ADD main1.py .`
`ADD main2.py .`
`ADD main3.py .`

`CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]`


**Commands i run:**

`docker build -t docker-test .`

`docker run docker-test main1.py`

**Error**

docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:380: starting container process caused: exec: "main1.py": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown.
ERRO[0001] error waiting for container: context canceled

Comment: You might try `docker run ... ./main3.py`, or setting `ENV PATH` in the Dockerfile so that the normal path lookup can find the scripts.  Also make sure the scripts are executable (running `chmod +x main*.py` on the host should carry into the image) and they start with a "shebang" line `#!/usr/bin/env python3`.  This should be the same things you need to do to run the scripts directly on the host, without Docker.

Comment: `docker run docker-test ./main3.py` gives the same error as mentioned above. If you have some free minutes, could you give me the full commands / Dockerfiles to the tipps you gave? Im new to Ubuntu cmd and docker so i dont know how to setup your advices

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing "theoretical" about this. Docker copies into place the files, and if they are working executables, you can execute them with `docker run image executable` ... but

- it requires the files to be properly executable (or you will need to explicitly say `docker run image python executable` to run a Python script which is not executable)
- it requires the files to be in your `PATH` for you to be able to specify their names without a path; or you will need to specify the full path within the container, or perhaps a relative path (`./executable` if they are in the container's default working directory)

  ```
  docker run image /path/to/executable
  ```
- you obviously need the container to contain `python` in its `PATH` in order for it to find `python`; or you will similarly need to specify the full path to the interpreter

  ```
  docker run image /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/executable
  ```

In summary, probably make sure you have `chmod +x` the script files and that they contain (the moral equivalent of) `#!/usr/bin/env python3` (or `python` if that's what the binary is called) on their first line.

(And obviously, don't use DOS line feeds in files you want to be able to execute in a Linux container. Python can cope but the Linux kernel will look for `/usr/bin/env python3^M` if that's exactly what it says on the [shebang line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).)

Answer (score 1):

In the specific case of a Python application, the standard Python [setuptools](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/) package has some functionality that can simplify this.

In your application's `setup.cfg` file you can declare [entry points](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html) (different from the similarly-named Docker concept) which provide simple scripts to launch a specific part of your application.

```
[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
  main1 = app.main1:main
  main2 = app.main2:main
```

where the scripts `app/main1.py` look like normal top-level Python scripts

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# the console_scripts call this directly
def main():
  ...

# for interactive use
if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Now in your Dockerfile, you can use a generic Python application recipe and install this; all of the `console_scripts` will be automatically visible in the standard `$PATH`.

```sh
FROM python:3.8
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN pip install .
CMD ["main1"]
```

```sh
docker run --rm my-image main2
```

It's worth noting that, up until the last part, we've been using generic Python utilities, and you can do the same thing without Docker

```sh
# directly on the host, without Docker
python3 -m venv ./virtual_environment
. ./virtual_environment/bin/activate
pip install .

# then run any of the scripts directly
main3

# technically activating the virtual environment is optional
deactivate
./virtual_environment/bin/main4
```

The fundamental point here is that the same rules apply for running a command on the host, in a Dockerfile `CMD`, or in a `docker run` command override (must be on `$PATH`, executable, have the correct interpreter, *etc.*).  See [@tripleee's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70289864) for a more generic, non-Python-specific approach.